# regex remove ref tags php

Tags: php, regex

Input string:

```
<ref> Hi this one to be rmoved} {{sdjfhk arbit shit}} [whatever] </ref> But this one to be preserved. <ref> again this has to be removed. </ref>
```

Output String:

```
But this one to be preserved.
```

i tried:  `$str = preg_replace('/^<ref.*?ref>$/', '', $str);`

Comment: I think there's an issue with your Input string. It looks like some formatting may have been lost. Can you verify its correctness, please?

Comment: To the down-voter: this is a relatively new user. Down-voting without a comment does not help condition users to become better ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close. You just want to drop your `^` and `$` characters.

```
$str = '<ref> Hi this one to be rmoved} {{sdjfhk arbit shit}} [whatever] </ref> But this one to be preserved. <ref> again this has to be removed. </ref>';

print preg_replace('/<ref.*?ref>/', '', $str);
//=> But this one to be preserved.
```

[See it working here on tehplayground.com](http://tehplayground.com/#4e4ca6eeaea7b)

---

Side note: Since you're looking for HTML tags, you should technically be using a DOM parser for this.

[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) is great for this kind fo task :)

Comment: i am a bit new, this little doubt: you use^ to say something beginning with, and use $ to say it ends with it, so where was i wrong??

Comment: The `^` means beginning-of-line, and the `$` means end-of-line.

Comment: Note, things differ from one regex implementation to another; see the following links pertaining to PHP's regex. More about [PHP regex functions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html). More about [Regex flavors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html).